# Diff on hibernate envers revisions

Tags: java, hibernate, compare, diff, hibernate-envers

This is a question related to:

[Hibernate Envers revision info (changes list)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9422331/hibernate-envers-revision-info-changes-list)

and

[Getting the old value and new value between two revisions with Hibernate Envers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17577363/getting-the-old-value-and-new-value-between-two-revisions-with-hibernate-envers)

Since these questions are a few years old I would like to know if there has anything changed?

> Is it now possible to retrieve diffs with envers?
>
> Or do I still have to load two revisions and compare them by myself in
>   Java?
>
> And if so - what's the best way to compare the two version in Java?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think anything's changed on the Envers side